# how to count distinct values in a column after groupby in scala spark using mapGroups

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am new to scala spark. i have a textfile data as

```
001,delhi,india
002,chennai,india
003,hyderabad,india
004,newyork,us
005,chicago,us
006,lasvegas,us
007,seattle,us
```

i want to count number of distinct city in each country so i have applied groupBy and mapGroups. I am not sure how to count values inside mapGroups.Please find my code below

```
val ds1 = sparkSession.read.textFile("samplefile.txt").map(x => x.split(","))
  val ds2 = ds1.groupByKey(x => x(2)).mapGroups{case(k,iter) => (k,iter.map(x => x(2)).toArray)}
```

Please help me with the syntax. I know it can be done easily by spark-sql but I want to do it by scala

Comment: Just replace `toArray` with `size` if you want count by city.

Comment: @leo if my cities are not distinct and i want to count distinct number of cities within each country then what is going to be the syntax??

Comment: @LeoC Please try answering my query posted above

Comment: Please see my posted answer.

Comment: @LeoC suppose i have an extra column(not given in my sample file) of which i want to calculate average grouping by  country then what should be the syntax. Thanks in advance

Comment: @LeoC i am trying something like val ds7 = ds5.mapGroups{case(k,iter) => (k,iter.map(x => x(8)).toArray.sum)}    but the syntax is not correct and its finding sum not average

Comment: I've expanded my answer for calculating `average`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count distinct cities per country, you can map the by-country list to an array of `city` and count the number of distinct cities:

```
val ds1 = spark.read.textFile("/path/to/textfile").map(_.split(","))
val ds2 = ds1.
  groupByKey(_(2)).mapGroups{ case (k, iter) =>
    (k, iter.map(_(1)).toList.distinct.size)
  }
```

[UPDATE]

To calculate average per country, say, from the 4th numeric column, the following would work:

```
val ds3 = ds1.
  groupByKey(_(2)).mapGroups{ case (k, iter) =>
    val numList = iter.map(_(3).toDouble).toList
    (k, numList.sum / numList.size)
  }
```

If you need various kinds of numeric aggregations I think Spark DataFrame API would be a more efficient tool (e.g. it has built-in `avg()`).

Answer (score 1):

The right way would be to do something like, `df` being your source dataframe ,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df: DataFrame = ???

val result = df.groupBy("country col name").agg(countDistinct("city column name").alias("city_count"))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it just count cities . not distinct cities

Comment: this is scala, using dataframe api. 
spark-sql would be something like `spark.sql("query here")`